# d3 v5 axis with Typescript = type errors

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I have some code which works fine but I'm new to TS, I think that I could define a type somewhere and d3's generics will kick in?

I have an `xAxis` and `yAxis` They are identical but D3 decided it doesn't like `xAxis`:

```
// formatAmount(n: number) => string

const xAxisRef = useRef<SVGSVGElement>(null)

const xAxis = useMemo(
  () =>
    axisBottom(xScale).tickFormat(n => '$' + formatAmount(n)),
  [xScale]
)

select(xAxisRef.current).call(xAxis)
```

Produces the following errors:

select(xAxisRef.current).call(**xAxis**)

> Argument of type 'Axis' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type '(selection: Selection, ...args: any[]) => void'.   Types of
>   parameters 'context' and 'selection' are incompatible.
>       Type 'Selection' is not assignable to type 'Selection |
>   Selection'.
>         Type 'Selection' is not assignable to type 'Selection'.
>           Types of property 'select' are incompatible.
>             Type '{ (selector: string): Selection; (selector: null): Selection; (selector: ValueFn<...>):
>   Selection<...>; }' is not assignable to type '{ (selector: string): Selection;
>   (selector: null): Selection; (selector:
>   ValueFn<...>): Selection<...>; }'.
>               Types of parameters 'selector' and 'selector' are incompatible.
>                 Types of parameters 'groups' and 'groups' are incompatible.
>                   Type '(SVGSVGElement | null)[] | ArrayLike' is not assignable to type
>   'SVGSVGElement[] | ArrayLike'.
>                     Type '(SVGSVGElement | null)[]' is not assignable to type 'SVGSVGElement[] | ArrayLike'.
>                       Type '(SVGSVGElement | null)[]' is not assignable to type 'SVGSVGElement[]'.
>                         Type 'SVGSVGElement | null' is not assignable to type 'SVGSVGElement'.
>                           Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'SVGSVGElement'.ts(2345)

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Comment: @DK2 unfortunately no I had to cast to any `.call(xAxis as any)` please let me know/answer this if you find a way. Edit: Actually just fixed it, just needed a bit more TS know-how! Will answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out it was pretty simple, since technically useRef(null) can be falsy (even if we know it isn't in a `useEffect` as long as the element is rendered) it needed a conditional check:

```
if (xAxisRef.current) {
  select(xAxisRef.current).call(xAxis)
}
```